# BETWEEN statement using PHP variables for dates

Tags: php, mysql

im using `$orderdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` to store in MySQL **datetime**

but when retrieving sales report which has a form of

```
    $initialstartdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $initialenddate = $_POST['enddate'];

    $startdate = " '$initialstartdate' ";
    $enddate = " '$initialenddate' ";

    $sql="SELECT * FROM orders 
    left join order_item on orders.order_id=order_item.order_id 
    left join products on products.product_id=order_item.product_id 
    left join category on products.category_id=category.category_id 
    where orders.order_date BETWEEN $startdate and $enddate;";
```

it is not showing dates and **BETWEEN** is not inclusive
maybe there is a problem regarding *H:i:s*
because it was working properly before changing this `$orderdate = date('Y-m-d');` to this `$orderdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

i tried concatenating `.'00:00:00'` to `$startdate` and `$enddate` but it didnt work

Comment: (Possible) side note: Learn to use parameterized queries. Your program is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: yes i know how but it is still testing

Comment: _...but it is still testing..._ Actually there is no reason for "but" :) you should start to learn what @stickybit said immediately

Comment: Using prepared statements not only prevents SQL injections, but it also **prevents quoting issues.** Using prepared statements now will remove all of the headaches that `$startdate = " '$initialstartdate' ";` and `$enddate = " '$initialenddate' ";` is attempting to fix.

Comment: my issue is mentioned in the question, i know how and i will use parameterized queries when my problem is solved. thanks :)

Comment: _..i will use parameterized queries when my problem is solved. thanks..._ You don't get the point

Comment: What are the dates in your variables, and what are the dates in your database? Is it not showing any results at all, or just not the ones you're expecting?

Comment: it is showing dates such as ( 2020-07-24 15:31:51 ) but $enddate is not inclusive @aynber

Comment: Correct. `Between` is not inclusive. So 2020-07-28 - 2020-07-28 will show no results, 2020-07-28 - 2020-07-29 will only show results for 2020-07-28. To make it inclusive, you have to pass in the timestamp for beginning and ending of the days -- 2020-07-28:00:00:00 - 2020-07-28:23:59:59 will give all of the results for the 28th, 2020-07-29:23:59:59 as the end date will give results for the 28th and 29th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is absolutely not safe for sqlingections. Use PDO and SQL preparing. Like this:

```
$start_date = $_POST['startdate'];
$end_date = $_POST['enddate'];

$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  

$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders 
    left join order_item on orders.order_id=order_item.order_id 
    left join products on products.product_id=order_item.product_id 
    left join category on products.category_id=category.category_id 
    where orders.order_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and STR_TO_DATE(:end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')");

$STH->bindParam(':start_date', $start_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindParam(':end_date', $end_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->execute();
```